# Average of two date columns

Tags: excel, date, range, formula

I've got two columns in my workbook with an open and close date, and I am looking to get an average date range (holding period) from the two columns. For example, if the open date in cell A1 is 19/11/2014 and the close date in cell B2 is 21/11/2014, the average holding period would be two days. I've attached a screenshot of the aforementioned columns to provide context. Any help on this would be great!

[image]

Comment: Just calculate the difference and format it as a general number.

Comment: thanks for responding. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: try this:  =DAYS(B2;A2)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @W_O_L_F, I've tried that but unfortunately it did not work

Comment: What is the result when you try? Could it be that your date columns are not formated as dates?

Comment: @W_O_L_F I have now reformatted them as dates. However I have tried the formula again and it says the formula you typed =DAYS(B2;C2) contains an error. I then tried it like this with a comma =DAYS(B2,C2) however this produced #NAME error in the cell

Comment: FYI The ; and , is country specific. Excel uses the region settings in windows to determine what sign to use. Unfortunate yes...I should probably start using , in all my post since that seams more common world wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for, based on your explanation is NOT an average, but rather the holding duration, being the difference between close and open date.
If you want, you can calculate (in a second step), the average of those differences.

I suggest you add to column C

```
=DAYS(B1,A1)
```

and you format that as Number.
Subsequently, you can calculate the average of the values in column C to get the average holding period for all your entries using:

```
=average(C:C)
```